# How to get the 2nd and 3rd character of a String as Integer - C89

Tags: string, parsing, type-conversion, integer, c89

So if I have a String

```
char string[4];
string = "A10";
```

How Can I get 10 as an Integer.
I tried getting 10 by itself using this but it didn't work.

```
char string[4];
char string2[2];
string = "A10";
string2[0] = string[1];
string2[1] = string[2];
```

I don't need to worry about the A, I know how to get that, I need to be able to get the 10 as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

In java you can use the following code to convert string to integer,

```
int i=Integer.parseInt(s2);
```

for more information view this website,
https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-to-int

Comment: The tag and comment says in C89